# CFMutableBitVector::CFBitVectorSetAllBits does not seem to work

Tags: objective-c, bit-manipulation, core-foundation

I am using CFMutableBitVector to manage a collection of bits, but the CFBitVectorSetAllBits API does not seem to work as expected. To illustrate the problem, consider the sample code:

```
vector = CFBitVectorCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 32);

printf("Setting all bits to 1\n");
CFBitVectorSetAllBits(vector, 1);

printf("Checking whether bit 0 is set... ");
isSet = CFBitVectorGetBitAtIndex(vector, 0);
if (isSet)
    printf("It is\n");
else
    printf("It is not\n");
```

The output I am getting is:

```
Setting all bits to 1
Checking whether bit 0 is set... It is not
```

If I use CFBitVectorSetBitAtIndex though, individual bits can be set or cleared just fine. Am I missing something here? Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CFBitVectorCreateMutable function creates **empty** vector and 2nd parameter specifies the capacity of vector, i.e. maximum number of bits that can be stored in it, but does not actually add any bits to the vector. You can add values to your vector using CFBitVectorSetCount function:

```
CFMutableBitVectorRef v = CFBitVectorCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 32);
CFBitVectorSetCount(v, 32); 
CFBitVectorSetAllBits(v, 1);
```